# VB.NET listview move files shown in the listview box

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a folder(1) that will fill up with files and those files will show in the ListViewBox with a checkbox next to it. I am trying to figure out that when Button1 is pressed and the checkbox next to the file name is checked, it will move that file to the next folder(2). (The idea is that there could be 10 files in the folder1 and the user could choose which files to move to folder2).

I am struggling to get the `For Each` loop working for me using `ListView`. I have tried using `My.Computer.Filesystem.Move` and `IO.File.Move`, but I am having a hard time tying them file name which changes with every file to the checked item in the listview box. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public MySource As String = "C:\DataEntryTest\LogFiles\"

    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim folderinfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(MySource)
        ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
        ListView1.CheckBoxes = True

        With ListView1
            .Clear()
            .View = View.Details
            .Columns.Add("Name", 150)

            For Each myFile As IO.FileInfo In folderinfo.GetFiles
                Dim myListItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(myFile.Name)
                .Items.Add(myListItem)
            Next
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate through the elements in ListView1 and move the required ones (and removing them from the list).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim destDir As String = "dir to move-to path"   

    With ListView1
        For i As Integer = .Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Items(i).Checked Then
                Try
                    Dim newPath As String = destDir & Path.GetFileName(.Items(i).Text)
                    If Not File.Exists(MySource & .Items(i).Text) Then
                        .Items(i).Remove()
                    Else
                        If Not File.Exists(newPath) Then
                            File.Move(MySource & .Items(i).Text, newPath)
                            .Items(i).Remove()
                        End If
                    End If
                Catch
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

NOTE: I am adding a try...catch, because "file management" tends to be problematic (and the `Move` method is quite unflexible).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to run this in my code and it allows it just fine and runs. But it does not move the file in the directory. It removes it from the listview which is something that I do need but it is not moving in the directories. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: @cbzcut6 I guess that you haven't inputted a right destination directory. Replace "dir to move-to path" with the whole name of the directory you want to move the files to (ending with a "\").

Comment: No, I have the Destination in there. I set it up again in my code and I can copy it over.

Dim destDir As String = "C:\DataEntryTest\LogFiles\ReportFolder\"

Using that it still only removes the name and not move the file. Thanks again!

Comment: @cbzcut6 Please, do a step by step execution and tell me what it does. If MySource is OK and the listview is populated with file names (without the directory), what is what your code delivers; everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! My source was not okay, missing the "\" at the end. Stupid mistake and I apologize for that. Thank you for your help and patience with me.

Answer (score 1):

In your button click event handler, loop through the `CheckedItems` collection, then move the file from the source directory to the target directory and append the correct file extension.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each itemChecked As Object In ListView1.CheckedItems
        Dim itemName As String = itemChecked.ToString()
        File.Move(Path.Combine(MySource, itemName), Path.Combine(MyTarget, itemName)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 For bringing the CheckedItems sub-collection into account.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It gives an error that the "Give Path Format is not supported" I have changed the formatting of it a few different ways and it still did not accept it. Do you think I could be missing a setup or import, etc? Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each itemChecked As Object In ListView1.CheckedItems
            Dim itemName As String = itemChecked.ToString()
            IO.File.Move(MySource & itemName & ".rpt", MyTarget & itemName & ".rpt")
        Next

    End Sub

Comment: See updated answer, which now uses `Path.Combine()` and appends the file extension to the `itemName` assignment.

Comment: I am not sure why you are adding the .rpt extension (or any extension at all). The OP is populating the list with filenames (including the corresponding extensions).